# Call a mapfragment in an AppCompatAcivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3, supportmapfragment

I'm trying to use a google map in the acitivty of a fragment pager, so the map stands behind the pager and still able to interact with it, but whatever i do i'm getting null exceptions.

i have tried to use SupportMapFragment as this:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Map));
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

But the getChildFragmentManager cannot be resolved because is an `AppCompatActivity` i guess.
is there another way to do it? is it possible? thanks.

Comment: Just change to getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding it dynamically instead.

```
        MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.llMapContainer, mMapFragment, "map");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

or else you can get the map fragment like this

```
        mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                   loadMap(map);
                }
           });
        }
```

Comment: thanks! i did it dynamically and worked really well :D